# Loop over batches of tensor images

Tags: python, tensorflow, generator, tensorflow-lite

I am using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to generate batches of tensor image data as below.

```
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    path_data_valid,
    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = "sparse", shuffle = False)
```

I want to send different batches of tensor image to my tensorflow SavedModel to get predictions **without** using predict_generator as follows:

```
model_predictions = new_model.predict_generator(validation_generator, (nb_validation_samples // batch_size + 1))
```

For the first batch I know how to do:

```
val_image_batch, val_label_batch = next(iter(validation_generator))
model_predictions = new_model(val_image_batch)
```

How about all batches?  how can I loop over batch of images?

The reason that I do not want to use predict_generator is that I want to invoke my tflite interpreter by setting every batch of images (val_image_batch) as an input as follows:

```
tflite_interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], val_image_batch)
tflite_interpreter.invoke()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can easily loop over the validation_generator and break it once it went trough all batches.

```
for val_image_batch, val_label_batch in validation_generator:
    cnt += 1
    tf_model_predictions = new_model(val_image_batch)
    tf_pred_dataframe = tf_pred_dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame(tf_model_predictions.numpy(), columns = dataset_labels), ignore_index =True)
    if cnt == nb_validation_samples // batch_size + 1:
        break
```